# Is there a way to return a value from a decision matrix with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to return a decision based on call duration and call reason. I want to use `index` and `match` but I don't know how to implement the match for call duration since I have 4 options and they are ranges.

Data table
[image]

Decision matrix
[image]

```
=INDEX(DM,MATCH('Call Data'!F2,'Follow Up Decision'!B4:B11,0),MATCH('Call Data'!E2,'Follow Up Decision'!C3:F3,1))
```

`DM` is the decision matrix table, '`Call Data`' and '`Follow Up Decision`' are both worksheets. I get either `0` or `N/A` every time. I need it to return the options in the decision matrix to cell `K2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE:

```
INDEX('Follow Up Decision'!C:F,MATCH('Call Data'!F2,'Follow Up Decision'!B:B,0),MATCH('Call Data'!E2,'Follow Up Decision'!$C$3:$F$3))
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.